# How to solve error in CDb connection in Yii framework

Tags: mysql, yii, connection, yii1.x

**I have an error when  trying to login to a Home page in Yii**

*This is error description*

CDbCommand не удалось исполнить SQL-запрос: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1. The SQL statement executed was: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `documents` `t` LEFT JOIN docpaterns as p ON t.type = p.id WHERE p.required = 1 AND t.status = 1 AND t.user_id =

*This is my code*

```
public function getDocsStatusNew() {
    // К новому модулю "документы"
    $reqDocPats = count(DocPatterns::model()>findAllByAttributes(['required' => 1]));

    $reqDocs = new CActiveDataProvider(Documents::model(), [
        'criteria' => [
            'join' => 'LEFT JOIN docpaterns as p ON t.type = p.id',
            'condition' => 'p.required = 1 AND t.status = 1 AND t.user_id = ' . $this->id,
        ],
    ]);

    if ($reqDocPats == count($reqDocs->data)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `$this->id` is undefined, so as you execute the sql `t.user_id = ' . $this->id,` returns `t.user_id =` and crashes. Fix this and it will work.

If you want to get the `id` of the current user that is logged in you could do:

```
Yii::$app->user->identity->id
```

So:

```
' AND t.user_id = ' . Yii::$app->user->identity->id,
```

Comment: When I print $this  it showes me Info about User Object ,,,where there is no id, how I can solve that how I can get the Id of the USER

Comment: Print $this->id if it has a number then this was not the problem, but as you shown the error, it look like $this->id was undefined.

Comment: when I print that  nothing will printed i think its null or undefined,

Comment: Then there you have your problem, fix that and the query will work. @Michael

Comment: @Michael check my answer on how to get the id of the current user that is loged in.

Comment: it showes this error

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Access to undeclared static property: Yii::$app in C:\OSPanel\domains\bestwaycoop_newwwwwwww\protected\models\Users.php:842

Comment: It is yii2 or yii?

Comment: this is yii just not yii2

Comment: then try `Yii::()app` instead of `Yii::$app` . But im not sure if then after, you still use user->identity->id or just user->id

Comment: http://bwbw2.paree24.com  go to this site and test it pressing the top right button and you will see

Comment: I write the Yii::app()->user->id,, and still showes nothing, the same result

Comment: @Michael then try `Yii::app()->user->identity->id` but for this to work the user has to be loged in.

Comment: do you try do to that site as I said? do you notice the error when press the top right Button where is written Личный Кабинет

Comment: Yes @Michael but I think the problem is bigger than that, im not loged in, I have no user id, I still did not log in, and you need the user id for that function, it will never work, check why you need that function there, but it seems that is a function that it has to be called when and only you are loged in and not before

Comment: I understand that thats why i want to  fix the error what it would be in that function

Comment: add this `Yii::app()->user->isGuest` before the call to the function, it returs true if user is not logged in and false if loged, so `if(!Yii::app()->user->isGuest) function`

Comment: Ok i will try and say